# Convert to a subroutine in Perl

Tags: perl, subroutine

I have this code, to extract in this case names, using a given list:

I want to convert this code in a subroutine, I have tried in a different ways but it just doesn't give me what I want.  And the other question is, how to add all the results (in this case: Barney Rubble, Wilma Flinstone) to the @match array without using a `foreach (@match){ push (@extract, $_)`?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my @array1 = ( "Fred Flinstone", "Wilma Flinstone", "Barney Rubble", "Betty Rubble" );
my @list = ("Ba", "Wil");
my (@match, @extract);

for (@list){
    my $unit = $_;
    chomp $unit;

    @match = grep (/$unit/, @array1);

    foreach (@match){
        push (@extract, $_);
    }
}

foreach (@extract){
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: You can use [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) to push the `grep`'d data into `extract`.  You could simply use `push @extract, @match;` too.

Comment: Looks like you're doing an excercise from _Learning Perl_. That's a good resource. :) Don't use `-w` on the shebang though. Use the `use warnings` pragma instead.

Comment: For the subroutine part of your question, you need to tell us which data is lexical (so only available inside of) the subroutine and always the same, which data comes in as parameters, and if there is anything that's available outside and inside the subroutine. There are a million ways to do that, but we don't know what you want to do.

Comment: You can use [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) to push the `grep`'d data into `extract`.  You could simply use `push @extract, @match;` too, and the explicit `@match` is superfluous: `push @extract, grep /$unit/, @array1;` does what's needful in one line.  The `chomp` isnt needed here, and you can name the values from `@list` with `foreach my $unit (@list) { push @extract, grep /$unit/, @array1; }`.

Comment: Can you show us a failed subroutine attempt so we can see which part is hard?

Comment: Hi, thanks for all. I want to make a subroutine to extract a given list of scientific name of bacteria as array (@array1) and taxonomic assignation obtained from metagenomics (QIIME) analyses (@array2),  I need a piece of code that compare the list with the taxonomic file and extract it, this scrip has the same principle (compare two list), and I just want a subroutine that take 2 array (list) and extract the list that match, the point is that I have like 5 variant but at the end I always have 2 array (list and taxonomic assignation) I tried to make a sub extract

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

sub build_re { "(?:".( join '|', map quotemeta, @_ ).")" }

my @strings = ( "Fred Flinstone", "Wilma Flinstone", "Barney Rubble", "Betty Rubble" );
my @substrings = ( "Ba", "Wil" );

my $re = build_re(@substrings);
my @matches = grep /$re/, @strings;
```

Notes:

- This code includes a sub (as requested).
- This approach is much faster.
- This approach fixes your duplicates problem. (For example, it doesn't add  `William Bates` to `@matches` twice like your code does.)
- This approach is stable. (The outputs are in the same order as the inputs.)
- This code uses somewhat more reasonable variable names.

---

> *how to add all the results to the @match array without using a `foreach (@match){ push (@extract, $_)`?*

```
foreach (@match) { push (@extract, $_); }
```

is equivalent to

```
push @extract, @match;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub multi_grep {
    my $checks = shift;
    my %seen;
    for my $check (@$checks) {
        ++$seen{$_} for grep $check, @_;
    }

    # This ensures we don't remove duplicates.
    # It also happens to make this approach stable.
    return grep $seen{$_}, @_;
}

my @array1 = ( "Fred Flinstone", "Wilma Flinstone", "Barney Rubble", "Betty Rubble" );
my @list = ( "Ba", "Wil" );  # Expected to be regex patterns.

my @matches = multi_grep(\@list, @array1);
```

Notes:

- This code moves the code into a sub (as requested).
- This approach fixes your duplicates problem. (For example, it doesn't add `William Bates` to `@matches` twice like your code does.)
- This approach is stable. (The outputs are in the same order as the inputs.)